# How to develop a web application from EER diagrams?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am looking for advise on how to develop a web application in Symfony2 by starting from a EER diagram. I appreciate a step-by-step primer of what you think is a reasonable way to develop.

Also, is there anything I should pay attention to avoid later failure?

Please suggest any tool I may use.

UPDATE: Let me clarify. Say I have the EER diagram below. A question is: is there a tool to convert it into symfony entity classes, with correct  annotations about relationships (1:N, or N:M)?

[image]

To clarify even more.
Say I have developed a EER diagram as above.
By Workbench Export, I may get the sql queries to create the corresponding mySQL tables; hence I may use Doctrine/Symfony2's `app/console doctrine:mapping:import` to get a schema I may use to generate my Entity classes.
However all that is not exactly what I am looking for, since I would like to avoid that piece of reverse engineering. So, question is: is there a way to export a EER diagram to the Entity classes **directly**, and to leave  mySQL table creation as really the last step?

If that is not really possible by Workbench/Doctrine/Symfony, is out there a different combination of tools which let me do so? (Zend; Ruby on Rails, ...)

UPDATE, it seems that Skipper [Skipper](https://www.skipper18.com/) does what I am looking for. Unfortunately it is not free/opensource (indeed a little pricey). Skipper has  a *export to ORM* tool, which creates Entity classes for Doctrine (or other ORMs) from a EER diagram. I need to check how it performs with respect to relationships and annotations.

Comment: I found a method to do this that is free :), please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from your EER diagram to define which doctrine entities your application is going to need and the relationship between them ( Note : If the relationships are not easy to spot you might need a class diagram ). Then I would suggest to follow an MVC design pattern for which Symfony is clearly oriented :

- Once you have your entities you have your models.
- Take a moment to define which routes your application is going to use
- The easiest way to deal with controllers is to assign a different controller for each route (unless you really have a lot of routes)
- Finally write your views to render your models and logic to the users.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ocramius did in Doctrine ORM Module (for Zend Framework) a tool to visualize Entities diagram. It really helps to visualize the diagram to configure your objects relations...

I liked it in Zend, and used it a lot ! so I really missed it when I started to learn Symfony... I decided to find a way to do the same... and I did ! (it uses the yuml.me API)

I shared the bundle :

https://packagist.org/packages/onurb/doctrine-yuml-bundle

Installation is very easy in only 3 steps... Try it :)

Comment: I see and it works. Nice, thanks. However, I am looking for the other way around: from an EER diagram to entity classes and Doctrine annotations. –

Comment: I see, pretty busy for soem time, as soon as I have  time I'll check it. I let you know, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a really nice script to do this.  It converts the EER Diagram to Doctrine 2 entities which are symfony friendly and it allows you to totally customize how its done.

The first step is to download this tool (https://github.com/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter/doctrine2-exporter).  I just installed it via composer (follow instructions on the github)

Next have the .mwb file be in the same directory as the script I am going to propose you make.

Next I created a script like this to customize the settings of that program.

**autodoctrine.sh**

```
php vendor/bin/mysql-workbench-schema-export youreerdiagram.mwb ./entities << EOF
`#Export to Doctrine Annotation Format`                                     1
`#Would you like to change the setup configuration before exporting`        y
`#Log to console`                                                           y
`#Log file`                                                                 doctrineconvert.log
`#Filename [%entity%.%extension%]`
`#Indentation [4]`
`#Use tabs [no]`
`#Eol delimeter (win, unix) [win]`
`#Backup existing file [yes]`
`#Add generator info as comment [yes]`
`#Skip plural name checking [no]`
`#Use logged storage [no]`
`#Sort tables and views [yes]`
`#Export only table categorized []`
`#Enhance many to many detection [yes]`
`#Skip many to many tables [yes]`
`#Bundle namespace []`
`#Entity namespace []`
`#Repository namespace []`
`#Use automatic repository [yes]`
`#Skip column with relation [no]`
`#Related var name format [%name%%related%]`
`#Nullable attribute (auto, always) [auto]`
`#Generated value strategy (auto, identity, sequence, table, none) [auto]`
`#Default cascade (persist, remove, detach, merge, all, refresh, ) [no]`
`#Use annotation prefix [ORM\]`
`#Skip getter and setter [no]`
`#Generate entity serialization [yes]`
`#Generate extendable entity [no]`                                          y
`#Quote identifier strategy (auto, always, none) [auto]`
`#Extends class []`
`#Property typehint [no]`
EOF
```

This will create the doctrine entities for you.  My particular settings turn on extendable entities because that way you can run this command over and over without overwriting model specific code.  You just put your code in the class that is extending the base class.  This will create a discriminator column in the database that you will want to ignore but its worth it for the logical separation.

Next you simply run the `/vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` console command like in the symfony tutorials to have it create the database from the doctrine files! Let me know if this was clear enough.

**References:**

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html